# Look up value between two matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing, matrix

I assume that I have a 2D matrix that range from 0 to 255 (size 2x3) and a 1D matrix (size 256x1). In which, 1D matrix stores the information of 256 pixel values of 2D array. For example, 
2D matrix is

```
[0 1 2
255 2 2]
```

and 1D matrix

```
[0 0 0.1 ....0.5]
```

I want to make a new 2D matrix that store the information of 1D matrix at each pixel value. We can see 2 in the 2D matrix has  value is 0.1 and 255 has information values is 0.5. So I want to make a matrix such as

```
[0 0 0.1
0.5 0.1 0.1]
```

How to make that matrix by MATLAB code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to index into the 1D array with the elements of the 2D array as indices. Now, MATLAB's indexing starts from 1 and you have values in the interval `[0,255]` in your 2D indexing array, so you need to add `1` to them before indexing. Thus, assuming `array1D`and `array2D` as the variable names for the 1D and 2D arrays respectively, use this -

```
array1D(array2D+1)
```

---

### Example

Let us assume some values for these two arrays as demo, shall we? Let `array2D` has 6 pixel values from `0 to 5` (to simulate `0 to 255` in your case) and `array1D` has 6 elements for each of the  6 pixels. The inputs and the code run -

```
array2D = [
    0 1 2 ;
    5 2 2]

array1D = [105 103 107 102 108 101]

out = array1D(array2D+1)

out =
105     103     107
101     107     107
```

Let's do the verification.

Now, `array1D(1,1)` was `0` and therefore `out(1,1)` must be the first element from `array1D`  i.e. `105`, is it? hell yeah it is!

Similarly, `array1D(1,2)` was `1` and thus, `out(1,2)` must be the second element from `array1D`  i.e. `103`, is it? YES!

...

`array1D(2,1)` was `5` and thus, `out(2,1)` must be the final element from `array1D` i.e. `101`, is it? YES!

... check the rest of the output elements for yourself?

Comment: sorry, maybe you don't understand what i need. I need to make a new 2D matrix that maps value from 1D matrix. In which, the value in orginal 2D matrix is index of 1D matrix. For example, 2 is a value of original 2D matrix. I will look up the value with index is 2 in 1D matrix and put that value into new 2D matrix. Thank you for your reply

Comment: @user3051460 Check out the example!

Comment: @user3051460 If the term `array` is confusing you, remember that you can denote any 1D or 2D or 3D or 4D data as arrays. Thus, 2D matrix can be called as 2D array.

Comment: @user3051460 Glad it finally made sense to you.